# Stopping site <site-name> because it failed during startup

Tags: wordpress, azure, nginx, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I'm currently trying to setup Bitnami's Wordpress + Nginx Docker with Azure App Service for Containers and I am stuck at the error message: Stopping site  because it failed during startup.

I already tried to increase `WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT` without success. I also tried to find anything in the other logs, however, there is not relevant information.

This is my log:

```
2021-03-26T20:26:39.850Z INFO - Starting multi-container app..
2021-03-26T20:26:40.686Z INFO - Pulling image from Docker hub: registry.hub.docker.com/bitnami/wordpress-nginx
2021-03-26T20:26:42.009Z INFO - latest Pulling from bitnami/wordpress-nginx
2021-03-26T20:26:42.011Z INFO - Digest: sha256:08ea17712bc6cd31a20128557aa5bbad562dc81af2e9a26b4f45bfca40e5538c
2021-03-26T20:26:42.013Z INFO - Status: Image is up to date for registry.hub.docker.com/bitnami/wordpress-nginx:latest
2021-03-26T20:26:42.021Z INFO - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 1 Seconds
2021-03-26T20:26:42.050Z INFO - Starting container for site
2021-03-26T20:26:42.052Z INFO - docker run -d -p 9180:80 --name as-wp-weu-prod_wordpress_0_f1793421 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=as-wp-weu-prod -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=as-wp-weu-prod.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=8d9749e1ad54987267d51cda41194309f78e9fe336b09f44ea04d81342bdd40c -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 registry.hub.docker.com/bitnami/wordpress-nginx
2021-03-26T20:56:42.520Z ERROR - multi-container unit was not started successfully
2021-03-26T20:56:42.546Z INFO - Container logs from as-wp-weu-prod_wordpress_0_f1793421 = 2021-03-26T20:26:49.138042862Z [0m
2021-03-26T20:26:49.138217863Z [0m[1mWelcome to the Bitnami wordpress-nginx container[0m
2021-03-26T20:26:49.138376864Z [0mSubscribe to project updates by watching [1mhttps://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress-nginx[0m
2021-03-26T20:26:49.138532065Z [0mSubmit issues and feature requests at [1mhttps://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress-nginx/issues[0m
2021-03-26T20:26:49.147750834Z [0m
2021-03-26T20:26:56.839294655Z nami INFO Initializing php
2021-03-26T20:26:56.907101461Z nami INFO php successfully initialized
2021-03-26T20:27:04.576803980Z nami INFO Initializing nginx
2021-03-26T20:27:04.676840017Z nami INFO nginx successfully initialized
2021-03-26T20:27:12.622656961Z nami INFO Initializing mysql-client
2021-03-26T20:27:12.721293503Z nami INFO mysql-client successfully initialized
2021-03-26T20:27:22.196788004Z nami INFO Initializing wordpress
2021-03-26T20:27:22.519271584Z wordpre INFO ==> Preparing Varnish environment
2021-03-26T20:27:22.527241945Z wordpre INFO ==> Preparing Apache environment
2021-03-26T20:27:22.537316623Z wordpre INFO ==> Preparing PHP environment
2021-03-26T20:27:22.588082613Z wordpre INFO WordPress has been already initialized, restoring...
2021-03-26T20:27:24.832051104Z mysql-c INFO Trying to connect to MySQL server
2021-03-26T20:27:24.861626532Z mysql-c INFO Found MySQL server listening at mariadb-weu-prod.mariadb.database.azure.com:3306
2021-03-26T20:27:25.130808807Z mysql-c INFO MySQL server listening and working at mariadb-weu-prod.mariadb.database.azure.com:3306
2021-03-26T20:27:25.130828007Z wordpre INFO Upgrading WordPress Database ...
2021-03-26T20:27:27.133719647Z wordpre INFO
2021-03-26T20:27:27.134393052Z wordpre INFO ########################################################################
2021-03-26T20:27:27.135004057Z wordpre INFO Installation parameters for wordpress:
2021-03-26T20:27:27.141716808Z wordpre INFO Persisted data and properties have been restored.
2021-03-26T20:27:27.142344313Z wordpre INFO Any input specified will not take effect.
2021-03-26T20:27:27.142926818Z wordpre INFO This installation requires no credentials.
2021-03-26T20:27:27.143452822Z wordpre INFO ########################################################################
2021-03-26T20:27:27.143975626Z wordpre INFO
2021-03-26T20:27:27.144505830Z nami INFO wordpress successfully initialized
2021-03-26T20:27:27.205315299Z [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Starting gosu...
2021-03-26T20:27:27.243704595Z [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Starting PHP-FPM...
2021-03-26T20:27:27.245663910Z [0m[38;5;2mINFO [0m ==> Starting NGINX...
2021-03-26T20:27:27.335050999Z 2021/03/26 20:27:27 [warn] 83#83: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:2
2021-03-26T20:27:27.335712104Z nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:2
2021-03-26T20:56:46.234Z INFO - Stopping site as-wp-weu-prod because it failed during startup
```

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: registry.hub.docker.com/bitnami/wordpress-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot:/bitnami/wordpress
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/server_blocks:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/wordpress-server-block.conf
```

Thank you!